# How can i add more than 1 input tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, element

This is my creat element tag:

```
const addinput = document.createElement("input");
```

This is my add btn:

```
const addbtn = document.querySelector("#plus")
```

Function is:

```
addbtn.onclick = function(){

    childrendiv.appendChild(addinput);

     addinput.style.width = "60vh";

     addinput.style.height = "5vh";

     addinput.style.margin = "3vh";

     addinput.style.fontWeight = "bolder";

     addinput.style.fontFamily = "'Lilita One', cursive";

}
```

How can I add more than one input tag in Javascript?

Comment: call `createElement` more than once!

Comment: I think I would declare `addinput` within the onclick function.

Comment: @DanielA.White that is incorrect with that code.

Comment: When you do `const addinput = document.createElement("input");` it creates one element. When you do append, it you are using that one element. Since an element can only live in one place it moves to that new location. If you want to have more than one you either need to clone it or you need to move the create line inside the function.

Answer (score 4):

Move the initialization of the `addInput` variable into the method:

```
addbtn.onclick = function(){

    const addinput = document.createElement("input");

    childrendiv.appendChild(addinput);
    addinput.style.width = "60vh";
    addinput.style.height = "5vh";
    addinput.style.margin = "3vh";
    addinput.style.fontWeight = "bolder";
    addinput.style.fontFamily = "'Lilita One', cursive";
}
```